# Using GPU resource in kubernetes deployment with minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am deploying an application which uses `gpu` in minikube locally. For that I am unable to mount gpu resouce on minikube. So I am getting

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  33s (x3 over 96s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu
```

For this I have seen couple of answers which suggested

1. KVM2 drive https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/nvidia_gpu/#using-the-kvm2-driver . I can't use it as it requires additional gpu cause it take one.
2. None driver https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/nvidia_gpu/#using-the-none-driver This require sudo access

Basically I can't use these method for this I found a workaround using which uses `docker` driver mentioned https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#preparing-your-gpu-nodes I was followed every steps installed

```
$ distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
$ curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
$ curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list

$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

in minikube nodes then deployed

```
$ kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin/v0.7.1/nvidia-device-plugin.yml
```

But when I see the resources with command

```
kubectl get nodes -ojson | jq .items[].status.capacity
{
  "cpu": "16",
  "ephemeral-storage": "959863856Ki",
  "hugepages-1Gi": "0",
  "hugepages-2Mi": "0",
  "memory": "32881396Ki",
  "pods": "110"
}
```

No gpu. To start minikube I am using following command

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a spare GPU or only the one your host sytem uses ?

Comment: @mario only one, but as mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212168/cannot-use-gpu-on-minikube-with-docker-driver there is a workaround using Nvidia container toolkit and Nvidia device plugin. I am trying to use that

Comment: Could you point out where specifically it is mentioned it can work on the same GPU, which is already used by the Operatig System ? As far as I know you always need to have spare GPU, that can be used by your k8s nodes.

Comment: It seems as though if you launch the outer container (the minikube vm, not the node) using nvidia-docker, it could work.  I haven't seen instructions, though. https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10229#issuecomment-765890153